# How to use switch cases inside JSX: ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, switch-statement, conditional-rendering

I have four components imported in my react app. How can i render one of the component conditionally (based on props). This is what i'm trying to do

```
<ReactSVGPanZoom
      //switch(this.props.Selected){
      // case '1': render <ComponentOne/>; break;
      // case '2': render <ComponentTwo/>; break;
      // case '3': render <ComponentThree/>; break;
      // case '4': render <ComponentFour/>; break;
      // default: render <ComponentOne/>
        }
</ReactSVGPanZoom>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Directly it's not allowed, because we can't put any statement inside JSX. You can do one thing, put the code (switch logic) inside a function and call that function, and return the correct component from that.

Check doc for: [**Embedding Expressions in JSX**](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx)

Like this:

```
<ReactSVGPanZoom
    {this.renderComponent()}
</ReactSVGPanZoom>


renderComponent(){
    switch(this.props.Selected){
        case '1': return <ComponentOne/>;
        case '2': return <ComponentTwo/>;
        case '3': return <ComponentThree/>;
        case '4': return <ComponentFour/>;
        default: return <ComponentOne/>
    }
}
```

**Suggestion:**

`break` is not required after `return`.

Answer (score 7):

You can just get the component from the switch (either in a function or in-line in `render`) and render it as a child of `ReactSvgPanZoom`, like so:

```
getComponent(){
  switch(this.props.Selected){
    case '1': 
      return <ComponentOne/>;
    case '2': 
      return <ComponentTwo/>; 
    // .. etc
    default: 
      return <ComponentOne/>
  }
}
render() {
    return (<ReactSVGPanZoom>
        {this.getComponent()}
      </ReactSVGPanZoom>);
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        (() => {
          switch(this.props.value) {
            case 1:
              return this.myComponentMethod();
              break;
            case 2: 
              return () => { return <AnotherComponent/> }; 
              break;
            case 3:
              return <div>1</div>; 
            break;
            default: return null; break;
          }
        }).call(this)
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: not sure about this solution, basically it is going to create a new function and self invoking it each time you render the component, which is something usually not desired

Comment: add the switch to dedicated function

Comment: Its actually not a real life example, dedicated function is definitely best solution for this. My code just shows in fancy way that it is possible

Answer (score 4):

You can create a const and use it whenever you need:

```
import React from "react";

export const myComponents = {
  Component1: <Component1 />,
  Component2: <Component2 />,
  Component3: <Component3 />,
  Component4: <Component4 />,
}
```

now in your main component:

```
import React from "react";
import {myComponents} from "./const";

...
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {myComponents[this.props.Selected]}
    </div>
  )
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mzn5x725vx

Comment: I was trying to find a better solution. But realizing that I am already using imho something that @max li suggested already. So I think this is the best answer for the question above.

Answer (score 3):

There's a construct for this purpose: [Do Expression](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-do-expressions/)

You can use it like this:

```
<ReactSVGPanZoom
    {do {
        switch (this.props.Selected) {
            case '1': <ComponentOne/>; break;
            case '2': <ComponentTwo/>; break;
            case '3': <ComponentThree/>; break;
            case '4': <ComponentFour/>; break;
            default: <ComponentOne/>;
        }
    }}
</ReactSVGPanZoom>
```

Just remember that you don't use `return` in do expressions and your last expression in the do expression will be the returned value. So even if you put a semicolon after switch it ruins things.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function FunctionName(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        (() => {
          switch (props.value) {
            case 1:
              return <p>Case 1<;
              break;
            case 2:
              return () => { return <AnotherComponent /> };
              break;
            case 3:
              return <div>1</div>;
              break;
            default: return null; break;
          }
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array index as dependency like this:

```
<Box>
    {
      {
        0: <ComponentOne/>,
        1: <ComponentTwo/>,
        2: <ComponentThree/>,
      }[arrayIndex]         // arrayIndex as dependency
    }
</Box>
```